# Microsoft SQL with more than one distinct COUNT and WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I have a data in Microsoft SQL server with the following format:

```
id1 id2 month   quantA  quantB  
1   10  1   5   15  
1   10  1   10  20  
1   10  2   5   10  
1   10  2   10  NULL  
1   11  1   NULL    NULL  
1   11  2   5   NULL  
1   11  2   10  5  
2   10  1   10  20  
2   10  1   5   NULL  
2   11  2   NULL    NULL
```

I need to construct a table grouped by `id1` and `month` with the following columns:

```
id1  
month  
var1 = count how many *distinct* id2 by month and id1 for which quantA!=Null  
var2 = count how many *distinct* id2 by month and id1 for which quantB!=Null
```

Comment: Could you format your question WITH line breaks !!?!?

Comment: What should the output table look like (for this given input)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the query basically how you have written it:

```
select id1, month,
       count(distinct case when quantA is not null then id2 end) as var1,
       count(distinct case when quantB is not null then id2 end) as var2
from t
group by id1, month
```

`COUNT DISTINCT` ignores NULLs when doing the count.